# Multiple aliases on one-line Python import

Tags: python, import, alias

Can I import module in Python giving it two or more aliases in one line?

With two lines this works:

```
from time import process_time as tic
from time import process_time as toc
```

This doesn't work, but I would want to be able to write something like:

```
from time import process_time as tic,toc
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would ever want to do this? In general it sounds like a fairly bad idea with no upside. Do you have a legitimate use-case?

Comment: @smci I would imagine they're trying to emulate `tic` and `toc` from languages they're more familiar with (matlab, R, etc), where functions with these names exist to measure elapsed time.

Comment: @coldspeed: but `tic` and `toc` are different things, they're not the same alias. `tic`: Starts the timer and stores the start time and the message on the stack. `toc` Notes current timer, computes elapsed time since matching call to tic(); when quiet is FALSE, prints associated message and elapsed time. I was worried that the question was phrased much more generally than *"How do I declare multiple aliases to process_time as tic, toc?"* Other people might conclude this was a good and healthy thing to do in general.

Comment: Is this question about a) the general case how and whether to create multiple aliases for an import (definitely a bad idea) or b) just the OP's very specific case of trying to using multiple aliases to make code superficially look like the original R/Matlab for `tic/toc`? (still not a great idea - just learn the Python equivalent already)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do that with

```
from time import process_time as tic, process_time as toc
```

Comment: Thanks Francesco, this is what i was asking for. However I think that the two lines solution is the more readable one.

Answer (score 7):

You could do

```
from time import process_time as tic

toc = tic
```

Comment: This is the best one. It makes it very explicit that it is an alias.