# Import multiple modules and creating alias in one line

Tags: python, import, alias

I want to do something like this

```
from folder import module_1, module_2 as m1, m2
```

instead of:

```
from folder import module_1 as m1
from folder import module_2 as m2
```

Just for the sake of practicality. How can I do it?

Note: it's not like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481111/multiple-aliases-on-one-line-python-import) because I want to import different modules

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The syntax was little off in the first block

```
from folder import module_1 as m1, module_2 as m2
```

Comment: Actually, it's mentioned in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)...