# Use multiple aliases for a module depending on whether another module exists or not

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-import

I am currently doing some work where `cupy` is involved. Overall, it makes my code run faster, since it is running everything on my GPU. Now, if a user does not have `cupy` installed, but he does have `numpy`, I would like to make the necessary adjustment. Currently, I am importing them like: `import numpy as np; import cupy as cp`. I can make the check discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it) to test if `cupy` is not installed, so that's not a problem. But I wouldn't like to put conditionals everywhere or change `cp` to `np`, since that would complicate things if `cupy` is indeed installed and I'd like to use that instead. So, I tested out the following (which in theory would solve my issue):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as cp

a = np.zeros((3, 3))
b = cp.zeros((3, 3))

>>> print(type(a))
    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print(type(b))
    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And it seems to work. Nevertheless, I found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481111/multiple-aliases-on-one-line-python-import) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940440/is-there-a-way-to-import-multiple-modules-under-one-alias)) where people pointed out that multiple aliases for an import was a bad idea, but I didn't find any elaboration on why that was the case.

Could someone elaborate on this topic and illustrate how to go about this when dealing with the use of a module (`cupy`) whose alias, if not installed, should point to another one (`numpy`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have another alias for a numpy import, why not just assign it?

```
import numpy as np
cp = np

# then just use it normally,
x = cp.arange(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this should be enough for my use case. I still have my doubts regarding the `import` twice though.